# Not loading a page 2nd time in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

In **page_1**, there is a table containing many rows with hyperlinks in every one of the rows, when **clicking** any of them it goes to **page_2** and suppose I scroll down to row number 100 which is almost at the bottom of the **page_1**.

In **page_2**, when I am clicking the **back button** of the **Chrome browser**, it gets back to **page_1** but it is **loading** the table again and remains at the top. But I want it not to load and remain at the bottom of the table row 100 in **page_1**.

In **Mozilla FireFox**, my condition is fulfilled automatically but not in case of **Google Chrome browser**.

is this achievable using ***javascript/jquery***? I am going through some solves but still not working yet!

Comment: Please add code snippet

Comment: Do you go back to page_1 by a link/button or with the browser-back-button? why not open the link to page_2 in a new tab, this will let page_1 at its current scroll-position

Comment: @wayneOS this is already implemented this way, and a legacy project! so changing things take a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

When you move to page_2 store the scroll location in some global variable with the below code.

var scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

Now when u come back to page_1 set the scrollTop again.

document.documentElement.scrollTop = scroll;

Comment: should I write them in <script> tag ? by the way I am using gsp

Comment: in which page should I set the value, in page_1 or page_2
 will it be like following:
var scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

and in which page should I set the scrollTop again?

Comment: Since page_1 is loading first so add the script in page_1, so there on click of any list item, store the scrollTop value to a global variable, and then launch page_2. 

When you come back to page1 from page2, access the global variable you have declared and set it to document.documentElement.scrollTop;